# Cognos 10 Date Format 'DD-MON-YY'

Tags: date, cognos-10

I am trying to change the date format for a Data Item Value in a Drill down crosstab report.

I have the date as a column above a query calculation and the row is the drill down hierarchy.  The only date format I can get to work is a cast(<value>,date) to work.  Would like to view the data format as DD-MON-YY, however with the cast statement you view it as yyyy-mm-dd.

I've tried using to_char, to_date, and combinations of both.  Nothing has worked.  Even using the Data Format in the properties provides no change.

Any advice?

Comment: What is the database vendor? (e.g. Oracle, DB2, MS  SQL)

Comment: The database vendor is Oracle 12g.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else. In Cognos 10.2.2, I was able to get the following date format 1-JAN-18 by using the Data Format property.

Select the "Date" Format Type

**Date Style:** Medium

**Date Ordering:** Day, Month, Year

**Display Eras:** No

**Display Years:** Yes

**Display Months:** Short name

Then, near the bottom, find the "Pattern" area. It won't work without this.

**Pattern:** dd-MMM-yy